# AngularJS Loading Twice, Resulting in Errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, outlook-addin

I'm developing an angular (1.7) application, and I'm having some problems due to the application loading twice. Basically, I have a huge front end application, and I'm trying to just take some parts of it and create an outlook plugin. The problem I'm having is that due to the app being loaded twice, all the other controllers I don't care about are also being loaded. See below for more clarification.

My app.js file looks as

```html
angular.module(APP, [
    'ui.router',
    'templates-outlook',
    'ngCookies',
]).config([
        '$locationProvider',
        '$urlRouterProvider',
        '$stateProvider',
        function ($locationProvider,  $urlRouterProvider,  $stateProvider,$sceProvider, $sceDelegateProvider) {
            
            console.log('APP.JS');

            if(Office !== "undefined") {
                Office.initialize = function (reason) {
                    Office.onReady().then((res) => {
                        console.log('wagamama', res);
                    })
                };
            }
            
            if (location.hash === '') {
                $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);  // HTML5
            } else {
                $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
            }

            $stateProvider
                .state('extension/', {
                    url: '/extension/',
                    templateUrl: 'templates/outlook/extension.html/',
                    controller: 'ExtensionController'
                });
                
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        }]) ...
```

In my index.php file, I have something like

```html
if (strncmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/extension/', 9) === 0) {
 require('./index.extension.php');
 exit();
}
```

The point of the above code is so that when a user visits 
http://8c6rr91e.ngrok.io/extension , the rest of the app doesn't load.

What is happening though is that the user goes to 
http://8c6rr91e.ngrok.io/extension

I see the following int he console:
APP.JS
Response: { .... // office stuff }

Then the page reloads, the url changes to http://8c6ec91e.ngrok.io/#!/ , the php check fails, and so it loads the whole app, resulting two errors:

1 - office is not defined
2 - All the other controllers in the main app being loaded and hence an injector error

My questions are:
- How do I avoid loading twice?
- Whats up with the #?

Thank you

Comment: Did you mean AngularJS 1.7? There is no 1.8

Comment: yes i mean that